# Question about moving index values after comparing array values in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

There is a chapter list of the book.
`let chapterList = self.bookDetail? .bookChapterList`
-> 7,49,73,109,163,195,236,241

I changed this string to an array

It will compare with `self.bookPage`

If `self.bookPage` is 25.

If I tap `previousChapterBtnTapped`,
If `self.bookPage` wants to go to 7 in the chapter list,

If `self.bookPage` is 68.

If I tap `previousChapterBtnTapped`,
I want `self.bookPage` to go to chapter 49 on the list.

```
@IBAction func previousChapterBtnTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        // ["7", "13", "113", "245", "311", "427"]
        let chapterListArr = bookDetail?.bookChapterList.components(separatedBy: ",")

    <<<i need...>>>
    <<< I will need to compare chapterListArr and self.bookPage. Please let me know your grammar.>>>    
    }
```

Comment: You need a `chapter` value that is lesser than the `Int` value of the `bookPage` that you specify? I don't understand your requirement properly

Comment: @PGDev That link is a comparison when looking for an exact number. What he wants to find out is which is the closest number below current bookPage. i.e: if chapter begins at 7 and ends at 12 and current page is 10, he want 7 as result. Or 1 as it's chapter 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert chapters to an array of integers and use lastIndex to find the previous chapter

```
let chapterListArr =  bookDetail?.bookChapterList.components(separatedBy: ",").compactMap { Int($0) } 

let index = chapterListArr.lastIndex(where: { $0 <= bookPage}) ?? 0
bookPage = chapterListArr[index]
```

This solution uses the index of the array so if bookPage is less than the first chapter (7) it will go to the first chapter. An alternative solution could be

```
if let index = chapterListArr.lastIndex(where: { $0 <= bookPage}) {
    bookPage = chapterListArr[index]
}
```

this will leave bookPage unchanged if it is less than the first chapter, to go to a specific page like 1 in this case just add an `else`

Comment: Even though this hasn't be specified by the OP, maybe use `<` instead of `<=` to go the previous chapter if you're on the first page of the current chapter. It would also be recommended to calculate `chapterListArr` outside of `previousChapterBtnTapped`

Comment: @ielyamani true but if we're on the second page of the chapter OP wants to go to the first page of the same chapter even if the function is named `previousChapterBtnTapped` so I think I stick with <=.

Comment: `<` would still take you to the first page of the same chapter.

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding of above mentioned information, you need to go to specific chapter but using pages array. Make a flag like start or end of the chapter along with pages array which identifies that this page is start or end of the chapter.

OR

You can keep two separate arrays one with pages and other with chapters information.
Just compare both arrays, chapter will be present in pages as same page respond to start and end.

Correct me if I am wrong with more detailed information.

Happy to help you, happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

So you want to figure out what chapter it is?

```
    var array = ["7", "13", "113", "245", "311", "427"].map{Int($0)!}

public func getChapter(from page: Int) {
    var currentChapter = 0
    array.enumerated().forEach({ (offset, chapterBeginning) in
        if page >= chapterBeginning {
            currentChapter = offset+1
        }
    })

    print(currentChapter)
}

getChapter(from: 311)
```

This will get you the current chapter. Convert it to int and look at each location if the page is greater or equal to the chapter beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `bookChapterList` is always sorted numerically, you can first convert the strings to `Int`, reverse the whole thing, keep dropping elements until the element is less than the page number, and take the first one after that.

```
let intChapterList = chapterListArr.map { Int($0)! }
self.bookPage = intChapterList.reversed().drop(while: { $0 >= self.bookPage }).first ?? 1
```

Note that I used `?? 1` to say that if all the elements have been taken (which means that we were at the first chapter in the first place), we go back to the first page. If your book's first page is indicated by `0`, change it to `?? 0`.